# Ключ Windows 10 с одного устройства на другое

Tags: windows-10, лицензирование, активация

Купил ноутбук. На старом компе стоит Windows 10. Могу ли я использовать тот ключ для активации винды на ноутбуке? При этом старый ПК мне уже не нужен. То есть, допускается вариант, что он из-за этого не будет работать.

Comment: Работать будет. Но если у вас OEM версия Windows, то это нарушение условий лицензирования

Comment: Если вы покупали бокс версию, то да.